# using void method to increment object by random double

Tags: java, methods, printing, increment, void

Im supposed to create a void method to increase or decrease a "coordinate" and am supposed to print the updated position in the main method. I'm having trouble with it.. I can't figure out how to call it in the main method so I can print it without the "updatePosition" method returning anything.

I'm definitely not asking anyone to write the code for me, but maybe point me in the right direction?

Here's the method:

```
public void updatePosition() {

    Double Longitude = new Double(position.longitude);
    Double Latitude = new Double(position.latitude);

    Random r = new Random();
    double myRand = -2.5 + r.nextInt(5);

    Longitude += myRand;
    Latitude += myRand;

    position.setLatitude(Latitude);
    position.setLongitude(Longitude);

}
```

Here's what I have as far as calling it in the main method:

```
    myGps.updatePosition();
```

Comment: Any reason you are using the `Double` wrapper class and not the primitive `double`?

Comment: Where is `position` stored? It isn't a temporary variable inside of your method, so what class "owns" it?

Comment: Which class is `position` member of ? I would say that if you have setters for `position.longitude` and `position.latitude`, you probably have getters that you could call in your main function to display the values.

Comment: I guess there's not really a reason I'm using the wrapper class Matthew.

Comment: position is stored inside of the same class the method is stored in, but a different one than the main method. The class name is Gps (the same class that myGps is from)

Comment: In the UML diagram I'm supposed to build this off of, there's no setters for the position, just getters

Comment: Have you tried doing printing out the result of the getter method for the position?

Comment: @Terra Would it be possible to see the diagram or the interface of the classes ?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to confuse students with UML diagrams instead of telling them basics like "how do I put *state* into some class" ... maybe you should step back from the material you are looking into right now; and instead you turn to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ... and work at least through the complete "Covering the basics" trail; before doing anything else. Teaching programming with UML diagrams; poor guy.